# При импорте исполняется дважды функция Python

Tags: python

Почему в консоли результат работы функции выводиться дважды? Как это работает? Пробовал по разному, результат одинаковый, всё равно дважды печатается, если убрать print, то один раз выводится.В вызываемой функции нету print.

```
from dll import han
z = han('qqq')
print(z)
```

Comment: Значит функция которую вы вызываете, вызывает другую функцию, которая вызывает print() =)

Comment: Покажите вызываемую функцию

Answer (score 2):

При импорте функции код модуля запускается на выполнение целиком. Так уж устроен Python. Для того, чтобы можно было как выполнять скрипт отдельно так и импортировать с него функции, тело скрипта прячут под конструкцией `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 1):

Раз в основном коде убираете print(z) и все равно выводит на экран, значит где-то в импортируемом коде есть вывод на экран. 
На экран, кстати можно вывести что-то не только print'ом.

```
sys.stdout.write('строка\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно сама функция что-то выводит и это создает дубляж.
Например:

```py
def han(s):
    print(s)
    return s

z = han("qqq") # напечатает первый раз
print(z) # второй раз
```

В данном случае будет дважды напечатано `qqq`, в первый раз когда приваиваете z, а второй когда выводите z.